# Почему this.field.sort в консоль сортирует а в DOM нет?

Tags: javascript, сортировка, объекты

```
class Game {
  constructor(parentElement, sizeX, sizeY) {

    this.field = [];
    let num = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < sizeX; i++) {
      this.field[i] = [];
      for (let k = 0; k < sizeY; k++) {
        if (k % 2 !== 0) {
          this.field[i][k] = new Cell(this.fielElement, num)
          num++
        } else
          this.field[i][k] = new Cell(this.fielElement, num)
      }
    };

    this.field.sort(this.createRandom); // ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
    console.log(this.field)
  }

  createRandom() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
  }
}
```

Ребят, подскажите, почему `this.field.sort` в консоль сортирует, а в **DOM** нет????

Comment: Сортировка ссылок на DOM-элементы в массиве не приведет к их перестановкам в DOM-е.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а каким образом можно реализовать сортировку ?

Comment: после сортировки массива - `appendChild` в цикле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сортировка элементов в JS массиве не влияет на их положение в DOM структуре. Вам необходимо выполнять манипуляции напрямую с DOM деревом. Для уменьшения затрат лучше в начале создать массив элементов, отсортировать, а затем добавить в DOM. Например:

```js
var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parent");
var elements = [];

//Create samples
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.innerHTML = Math.random();
  elements.push(newDiv)
}

//Sort elements
elements.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1;
})

//Insert into parent
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  parentDiv.appendChild(elements[i])
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```