# Перемешивает в консоле, а в DOMе не хочет

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты

```
constructor() {
     //код....//

            this.field = [];
            let num = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < sizeX; i++) {
                this.field[i] = [];
                for (let k = 0; k < sizeY; k++) {

                        this.field[i][k] = document.createElement('div');
                        this.field[i][k].className ='cell';
                        this.fielElement.parentElement(this.field[i][k]);
                        this.field[i][k].setAttribute('zzz', num);
                        num++;
                };
            }

            this.field.sort(this.createRandom)

        }
        createRandom(){
                return Math.random() - 0.5;
            }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/Почему-this-field-sort-в-консоль-сортирует-а-в-dom-нет - опять?